# I need a setup that runs in silent mode and "loud" mode. Installshield express. Does not appear to work

Tags: vbscript, installshield

InstallShield Express Custom Actions **“Before System Search (Silent Mode Only)” and “Before System Search (Not in Silent Mode**)” don’t appear to work as explained.

I have an installer that needs to work for silent and `“loud”` installs. I need one of these two `“sets”` to actually execute but not both (2 vb scripts under each). Depending upon if this is a `clean install` or a `maintenance install`, more than one set runs. I do not have steps under the Maintenance section.

This is my first attempt at a combined silent/loud install setup. I have been trying to get this to work for quit a while now. Trying different workarounds and express versions (2010, 2011).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the conditions for clean install & maintenance install. Please find the conditions below :

> For clean install : use `Not Installed` condition on your components
>   or sets or on actions.
>
> For maintenance install : use `Installed` condition on your components
>   or sets or on actions.